# Get count of multiple table records with group by function

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables : `priority_list` and `priority_list_delete`

I want to get the following data in a single row:

1) Sum of these 2 table records

2) Count of individual table records

3) Count of priority_list_delete table records category wise

This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM priority_list)+(SELECT COUNT(*) from 
priority_list_delete) as tot_count,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM priority_list) as prior_cnt,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM priority_list_delete) as prior_del_cnt
```

The above query returns the count of the tables but when I merge the below query with the above one, it throws an error:

```
(SELECT category, COUNT(*) FROM priority_list_delete group by category)
```

I guess, there is some syntax error which I am unable to sort it out and moreover I am not getting idea about how to get the count records category wise where category names will be the column name.

Example format:

```
 tot_count| prior_cnt| prior_del_cnt| ST   | OBC
 ---------|----------|--------------|------|------
 920      | 893      | 27           | 64   | 100
```

Here ST and OBC are the categories.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your exact desired output might be tough to do, because the number of category columns is dynamic.  But we can try reporting categories across rows:

```
SELECT category, cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS cnt, 0 AS pos
    FROM priority_list_delete
    GROUP BY category
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'prior_cnt', COUNT(*), 1 FROM priority_list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'prior_del_cnt', COUNT(*), 2 FROM priority_list_delete
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tot_count', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM priority_list) +
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM priority_list_delete), 3
) t
ORDER BY pos, category;
```

This would give an output looking something like:

```
category      | cnt
ST            | 64
OBC           | 100
prior_cnt     | 893
prior_del_cnt | 27
tot_count     | 920
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much. I am getting the records perfectly with your query. Thanks a ton. :)